# Checking ovelap of 2 arrays

Tags: java, arrays, junit, 2d, overlap

I am writing a method to test the collision of 2 arrays (just like Tetris). `grid` array and `movingShape` array. The arguments of this method are x and y coordinates. The method will take `movingShape` and the coordinates and loop over both array to see if the smaller `movingShape` is positioned on top of any filled cells in the `grid`. Return true if 2 arrays not overlap and false there is an overlap.

When I run the test, it didn't pass. Here is what I've got so far:

```
public boolean test_position(int x, int y) {
    for (int row = 0; row < movingShape.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < movingShape[row].length; col++) {
            if (movingShape[row][col] != 0) {
                grid[row + x][col + y] = movingShape[row][col];
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Some test:

```
    org.junit.Assert.assertTrue( "test_position( 0,5 ) start" , tet.test_position( 0,5 ) );
    org.junit.Assert.assertTrue( "test_position( 0,2 ) top left" , tet.test_position( 0,2 ) );
```

Comment: There's not enough code to understand what might be going on but a nested loop where the inner and outer loop is left unconditionally (`return`!) on the first iteration is quite unlikely.

Comment: Probably (!) you should omit the else-branch including return false. But I'm not sure about the role of array `activeShape`.

Comment: my bad, it should be movingShape as well

Comment: Shouldn't this `grid[row + x][col + y] = movingShape[row][col];` be something like `if (grid[row + x][col + y]) { return true; }` instead?

Comment: Where is the actual test that two cells overlap? - It's hopeless without a detailed explanation of what should be computed in this method.

Answer (score 0):

Because both of the `if/else` conditions in your loop `return` something, the nested loop can only iterate once and therefore only test cell. Also, as `5gon12eder` states, it seems that you are missing a check that the grid is not populated before assigning it. Finally, I would not assume that a method called `test_position` should update the grid.